# ms sql Adding 2 rows, based on data in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have a table (lets name it table1) with this:

```
Company, Account, OtherData
```

There are multiple accounts per company. There a multiple companies.

Now there are 2 types of companies: A-Type and B-Type. 
(type of the company can be derived from the name of the company - lets say they start with A or B)

Every A-Type Company has a matching B-Type company. Its a  1-1 relation. There is another table (table2) which maps company A to B

```
A-Type Company, B-Type Company.
```

What I would like to achieve is a result set that looks like that

```
A-Type Company, B-Type Company, 
Account (there are multiple accounts per company), 
OtherDataA (that came from A-Type row), 
OtherDataB (that came from B-Type row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert select statement. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

It works like this.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```